# Unable to redirect to Dropbox Authentication page

Tags: php, laravel, dropbox, laravel-5, dropbox-api

I'm building a simple app using Laravel that tries to authenticate to Dropbox to interact with its core API. I'm trying to redirect my users to the Dropbox page where they will be asked to Allow or Deny access to my app. I've successfully set up client ids and secrets and made some tests, however, I cannot figure out how to redirect to the external Dropbox page.
Here's my code :

```
public function syncDropbox()
{
    redirect ('https://www.dropbox.com/1/oauth2/authorize?client_id='.env('DROPBOX_ID').'&response_type=code');
}
```

I made the test to directly go to that page by typing it in my browser and replacing the client id with the referenced one and it goes to the dropbox website, what do I need to do to make my in-app redirect ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use:

```
return Redirect::away('url');
```

To redirect to an external site in Laravel. There may be a helper function for this called redirect_away()

Answer (score 0):

None of this worked, What actually worked was to change the code to :

```
  public function syncDropbox()
    {
       return new RedirectResponse('https://www.dropbox.com/1/oauth2/authorize?client_id='.env('DROPBOX_ID').'&response_type=token&redirect_uri='.env('DROPBOX_REDIRECT_URI'));
    }
```

This did the trick.

Comment: Ahh laravel 5? Completely looked over that tag. Glad you got it working nonetheless.

Answer (score -1):

Use HTML redirect to do this... plain simple... You just need to "echo" the code.

```html
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/" />
```